# Django annotate - get attribute of all related objects

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

I have such a models:

```
# models.py
class A(Model):
    ...

class B(Model):
    parent = ForeignKey(A)
    comments = ForeignKey(Comments)

class Comments(Model):
    title = CharField(...)
```

How, using `annotate` method of queryset, I can get all titles of `B`s' comments related to some `A` queryset?

I tried:

```
result = A.object.all().annotate(b_titles=F("b__comments__title"))
```

but it returns only first object.

`FilteredRelation` also didnt help (*`FilteredRelation's condition doesn't support nested relations`*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with `ArrayAgg` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/)
- available only using Postgres.